# What is taking bites out of my lily pads?

Tags: pond, lily

I have a single lily pad plant in a very small pond, about 3-4 feet in diameter. There are no turtles.

Recently the leaves have been ravaged by something which is eating them *from the rim inwards*. It looks like somebody took a bite out of the lily pads, like a bite out of a cookie. The bites are about an inch in diameter. What could be doing it?

Comment: Have you looked to see what's under the lily pad?  Snails might be living there...